# How do browsers locate background-image in CSS?

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to find out why a background image isn't appearing.

By default, do browsers look for referenced images in the same folder as the style sheet or the script calling the style sheet?

Ex.
Script is /foo/bar.html
Stylesheet is /css/site.css

site.css contains:

```
.header {background-image: url(beautiful.png);}
```

Is the browser expecting the file beautiful.png in /foo, or /css?

Also, is it acceptable to reference this image by using the webroot? Ex:

```
(file in /images/styles/)
.header {background-image: url(/images/styles/beautiful.png);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [relative to the style sheet, not the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-uri):

> In order to create modular style sheets that are not dependent on the
>   absolute location of a resource, authors may use relative URIs.
>   Relative URIs (as defined in [RFC3986]) are resolved to full URIs
>   using a base URI. RFC 3986, section 5, defines the normative algorithm
>   for this process. For CSS style sheets, the base URI is that of the
>   style sheet, not that of the source document.

Root relative paths (leading slash) are fine and what I usually use.